# How spin orbit coupling breaks mirror symmetry?

Tags: quantum-spin, crystals, magnetic-moment, spin-orbit, mirror-symmetry

I have been studying in several research papers with statement that spin orbit coupling breaks the all three mirror symmetry in cubic crystals when the magnetization direction is along the (110) direction. I am not able to understand how SOC can break these mirror symmetries. Please clarify this.
Thank you!

Link to papers: [here](https://doi.org/10.1002/advs.202100782), [here](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.117.236401)